# Ethernet cable choice for home wiring?

Tags: wiring, ethernet, cable-management

... Apologies if this is the incorrect forum for hardware recommendations...

I'm planning on wiring my Portland, OR (cold & damp, but non-freezing climate) house for Unshielded Cat 6 or Cat 6a ethernet.  I enjoy this kind of long project.  I'll be running in various locations and don't know which type of wire I should choose for the various locations. No buried or wet runs, BTW, but they do come close to the elements.   I don't need any gel-filled direct burial.  I'm very knowledgable about wiring types, terminations, keystones, patch panels, and low voltage installation so please be technical.  I Just ran lots of Cat 6 in my dad's new basement for his 8K TV. (My dad ONLY watches the talking heads, BTW!)  My wires will come to a closable cabinet in my finished basement.  The cabinet will house my fiber modem router, switch, UPS, and NAS.  The wires will go out to different locations in the house through different conditions:

1. Out the back of the cabinet into my covered non-temperature controlled closed garage.  This visible cable run will run up to the ceiling and go through the joists along the ceiling, around the garage and into a connected under-porch storage area.  It will run up and enter the front wall of the house.  This will run a Ring Doorbell via PoE.  Does this need Exterior gel-filled cable.
2. Out the back of the cabinet and behind the wall around the indoor inside of the foundation of the house.  The finished basement walls were installed about 4 inches away from the foundation for insulation.  Wires can be fished through there.

   -- One wire will travel 50ft around the basement along the foundation and up the inside of exterior uninsulated wall to an external backdoor outdoor webcam powered via PoE.  Outdoor or Riser?

   -- One wire will run along the inside of the foundation (behind the basement's finished walls) and then up into a desk in the kitchen.  The foundation doesn't freeze, but it gets cold.   Riser?

   -- One wire will run 50ft along the foundation and then have a short run *under the house* through the joists.  Covered but there are spiders.  I hate spiders.  Outdoor for this run?
3. Up from the basement cabinet in the wall alongside the side of the 1910 chimney (directly above this cabinet on the first floor) up to the second floor. There's enough of a gap between the bricks and the floorboards/ceiling to run several wires up.  These will be run all the way up to the the attic floor/second floor ceiling (which I am re-doing) and then dropped down various walls for TV/workstation jacks as well as the upstairs WiFi access point.  Cat 6 Riser for this.

I don't want to violate code by running outdoor cable when I should have run Riser.  I didn't want to find that I should have used gel-filled under my porch or under the house.  Alternatively, I didn't want to run Riser under the porch only to have it disintegrate due to the cold.  Or find that my outdoor cable needed to breathe more or something.  I also didn't want to worry about the cable jacket breakdown since it will be running along the inside foundation.

Thanks so much,

DW

Comment: Have you considered running ENT or comms duct for your cables instead of simply having them directly in the walls, btw?

Comment: Wherever you install your wiring put it in conduit, so when you need to replace a run all you'll need to do is to pull the new wire through.

Comment: Installing a comm duct is a good idea.  I actually have a decommissioned chimney on the opposite side of the house that I could use.  That would get me to the attic.  I'd still have to run the wires around the second floor and down the walls.  I could certainly install conduit under the house.  That wouldn't be so hard.  It's impractical for me to run the conduit around the back of the basement walls, though.  There'd be no way to affix it to the foundation's rimmer boards.    Do I have to use outdoor cable in the conduit if I'm running through the non-climate controlled areas?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Anything helps.  This site is so great.  Actually, I just looked up ENT.  That would work around the backs of the walls in the basement especially to protect the cables.